# Mobile safari not handling custom jQuery trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, mobile-safari

I have custom event triggers to show an alert at the top of the page when an action is taken. As a React component, my alert bar creates custom event listeners with `$(window).on('alert', this.onAlert)`. These events are triggered by many actions: data loading, click success affirmations, etc., using `$(window).trigger('alert', {...})`.

On Safari mobile, these events are not triggering. Everywhere else they will, so what am I missing here? Are there resources I could use? Searching on this topic is hard.